# How to align "sup" in h1 with big font

Tags: html, css, superscript

I am making a website where I have a h1 with a large font size. What I am trying to do is to make a superscript that is aligned to the top of the text but no matter I do sup is not aligned properly.

Here is the plunk of what I am working on! 
http://plunker.co/edit/gnS915O9PVAe9VKktqFh?p=preview

So in this plunk, I am trying to make "TM" a superscript of ACME. However, it

Mark up is this :

```
  <h1>
    acme
    <sup>TM</sup>
  </h1>
```

Style is this:

```
  body {
    padding: 60px;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 12em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1em;
  }

  h1 sup {
    font-size: .1em;
    vertical-align: super;
  }
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? The proper way to use a trade mark symbol is to use the “™” character. If you disagree with the font designer on its appearance, use other fonts.

Comment: I need to make 'TM' proportionately smaller. Then how do you make the ™ stand next to the letter E with a smaller font size. Wrapping it in an inline element and setting font-size does not work for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Set the vertical align and the line height:

```
 h1 sup {
    font-size: .1em;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin-left: -30px;  
  }
```

I updated the answer to push the sup to the left with a negative margin.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/T45y7ob43mdNY3fvC73S?p=preview

Comment: Thanks ... Tried this before ...Can I align TM on right next to top of letter "E" not above it?

Comment: Sure just margin-left: -30px;

Comment: No problem, just add line-height: 40px or however many you need to get it where you want it.

Comment: I tried vertical-align:xx% but when h1 resizes alignment breaks.

Comment: @learning_bee try do everything in `ems` instead. Something like: `h1 sup {font-size: .25em; vertical-align: top; line-height: 1.75em; margin-left: -1em;}` then the `sup` will resize with `h1`

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could make this work (at all) in Chromium 24/Ubuntu 12.10, is to use:

```
h1 sup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: .1em;
    top: -2em;
```

}

[(Forked, I think) Plunker demo](http://plunker.co/edit/MGRTFA7pegnlhkRBSuGz?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

Your extra linebreak after acme is making it wrap to the next line... See your forked [PLUNKER](http://plunker.co/edit/ncPRcSe95UNblunZiyq4?p=preview)

```
  <h1>
    acme<sup>TM</sup>
  </h1>
```

Comment: Its not breaking just the view port is not quite wide.